# ROLLBACK in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, transactions, rollback

Clearly I am misunderstanding rollbacks in PostgreSQL, why doesn't work this piece of script?:

```
do $$
begin
        insert into mytable values (1);
        insert into mytable values (1);
exception when others then 
        ROLLBACK;    
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 13 at SQL statement
********* Error *********

Comment: Because functions (and a `DO` block is also one) are not allowed to explicitly commit or rollback a transaction:

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, do you mean there is no way to rollback in a function? The only thing I want to achieve is creating a script which execute some INSERTs inside a transaction and if something goes wrong then rollback all those INSERTs, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to do the transaction handling *outside* the function.

Comment: @JeroLopez You do not need to explicitly call `ROLLBACK`. An uncaught exception inside a function will cause rollback automatically.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that was what I was missing.